# count number of missing values in netcdf file - R

Tags: r, netcdf

Is there a quick way to know how many missing values are in a netcdf file? Possibly using R.

Currently I have to

```
hum<-nc_open("rhum.sig995.2008.nc")
rhum<-ncvar_get(hum, "rhum")
```

then manually look up the missing value by typing 'hum' and copy it into this operation

```
sum(abs(rhum - 9.96920996838687e+36) < -9.96920996838687e+36)
```

Is there a more direct way, especially if I have to work with hundreds of files? I would like to avoid copying and pasting the missing value, and also I am not sure with what kind of precision the number should be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the excellent raster package:

```
install.packages(raster)
library(raster)

r <- raster("rhum.sig995.2008.nc", var="rhum")

NAnum <- summary(r)[6]
```

Comment: Or use  `freq(r, value=NA)`

Answer (score 2):

The total number of missing data points for variable names "var" can be stored in a new additional variable using

```
ncap2 -s "nmiss=number_miss(var)" in.nc out.nc
```

or

```
ncap2 -s "nmiss=var.number_miss()" in.nc out.nc
```

If your data has a time dimension and you want to see the total number of missing points summed over the space dimensions, then you can see this with

```
cdo info in.nc
```