# How to calculate number of missing values summed over time dimension in a netcdf file in bash

Tags: bash, missing-data, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have a netcdf file with data as a function of lon,lat and time.  I would like to calculate the total number of missing entries in each grid cell summed over the time dimension, preferably with CDO or NCO so I do not need to invoke R, python etc.

I know how to get the total number of missing values

```
ncap2 -s "nmiss=var.number_miss()" in.nc out.nc
```

as I answered to this related question:
[count number of missing values in netcdf file - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948782/count-number-of-missing-values-in-netcdf-file-r/43902418#43902418)

and CDO can tell me the total summed over space with

```
cdo info in.nc
```

but I can't work out how to sum over time.  Is there a way for example of specifying the dimension to sum over with number_miss in ncap2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added the missing() function to ncap2 to solve this problem elegantly as of NCO 4.6.7 (May, 2017). To count missing values through time:

```
ncap2 -s 'mss_val=three_dmn_var_dbl.missing().ttl($time)' in.nc out.nc
```

Here ncap2 chains two methods together, missing(), followed by a total over the time dimension. The 2D variable mss_val is in out.nc. The response below does the same but averages over space and reports through time (because I misinterpreted the OP).

Old/obsolete answer:

There are two ways to do this with NCO/ncap2, though neither is as elegant as I would like. Either call assemble the answer one record at a time by calling num_miss() with one record at a time, or (my preference) use the boolean comparison function followed by the total operator along the axes of choice:

```
zender@aerosol:~$ ncap2 -O -s 'tmp=three_dmn_var_dbl;mss_val=tmp.get_miss();tmp.delete_miss();tmp_bool=(tmp==mss_val);tmp_bool_ttl=tmp_bool.ttl($lon,$lat);print(tmp_bool_ttl);' ~/nco/data/in.nc ~/foo.nc
tmp_bool_ttl[0]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[1]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[2]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[3]=8 
tmp_bool_ttl[4]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[5]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[6]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[7]=1 
tmp_bool_ttl[8]=0 
tmp_bool_ttl[9]=2
```

or

```
zender@aerosol:~$ ncap2 -O -s 'for(rec=0;rec<time.size();rec++){nmiss=three_dmn_var_int(rec,:,:).number_miss();print(nmiss);}' ~/nco/data/in.nc ~/foo.nc
nmiss = 0 

nmiss = 0 

nmiss = 8 

nmiss = 0 

nmiss = 0 

nmiss = 1 

nmiss = 0 

nmiss = 2 

nmiss = 1 

nmiss = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, upvote as it allows me to see the answer from the command line, but I was hoping to have the answer in a 2D netcdf file.  I suppose adding a hyperslice functionality to nco , e.g.  ncap2 -s "nmiss=var.number_miss(x,:,:) is probably complicated?  I am not very familiar with ncap2.

Comment: We already have implemented and use syntax similar (e.g., avg=var.avg($lat,$lon)) to that which you suggest, only for averages, max/min, etc. I don't know why we did not implement that for number_miss(). Since you asked, we will put it on the TODO list :)

Comment: never followed up to say thanks for implementing this, has been really useful over the years, just using it again now.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are asking for another solution, I would like to show you that it takes only one very short line to find the answer with the help of Python. The variable `m_data` has exactly the same shape as a variable with missing values read using the `netCDF4` package. With the execution of only one `np.sum` command with the correct axis specified, you have your answer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4 as nc4

# Generate random data for this experiment.
data = np.random.rand(365, 64, 128)

# Masked data, this is how the data is read from NetCDF by the netCDF4 package.
# For this example, I mask all values less than 0.1.
m_data = np.ma.masked_array(data, mask=data<0.1)

# It only takes one operation to find the answer.
n_values_missing = np.sum(m_data.mask, axis=0)

# Just a plot of the result.
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(n_values_missing)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('lon')
plt.ylabel('lat')
plt.show()

# Save a netCDF file of the results.
f = nc4.Dataset('test.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
f.createDimension('lon', 128)
f.createDimension('lat', 64 )
n_values_missing_nc = f.createVariable('n_values_missing', 'i4', ('lat', 'lon'))
n_values_missing_nc[:,:] = n_values_missing[:,:]
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it is concise in python, upvote for the answer, I may have to do this in python I think, I can always write the field back out to an netcdf I suppose

Comment: I added a piece of code that shows you how to save to netcdf.

Comment: Chiel, I like your answer and it is compact and neat, but I switched the accepted answer to the updated NCO solution as it allow me to do the operation from the command line.  Both answers are excellent.